Running flutter pub get and getting "<< was unexpected at this time." in return
I have pulled the source code for my app from GitHub and put it in a directory on my local machine.
When I try to run flutter pub get I get this message in return:

<< was unexpected at this time.

I have tried to find some references to this but I have not found anything.
I am using Windows 11 and VSCode.
What does this mean and how can I run flutter pub get?

what about other flutter commands! just to make sure there's no problem with flutter itself. and btw, recheck where these commands are initiated and make sure you are in the root of your project if not navigate to it through cd.

you can check this similar problem here
